# Coordinates in Local Immersion Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

The statement of **Local Immersion Theorem** as follows:

Suppose that $f:M\rightarrow N$ is an immersion at $x\in M$ and $y\in N$. Then there exists local coordinates around $x$ and $y$ such that $$f(x_1,\dots ,x_k)=(x_1,\dots,x_k,0,\dots,0)$$
In other words f is locally equivalent to the canonical immersion.

I understood the proof completely. But I have a problem in the statement itself. I could prove that *f is locally equivalent to canonical immersion*.

But how does that imply the existence of the coordinates around x and y such that f takes the above form.

Edit:
I could prove that there exist $\phi: U\rightarrow U'$ and $\psi: V\rightarrow V'$ where $x\in U',y\in V'$ such that $\psi^{-1}f\phi=cannonical~immersion$.

But how does that imply there exist local co ordinates such that
$$f(x_1,\dots ,x_k)=(x_1,\dots,x_k,0,\dots,0)$$.

Please let me know if you still do not get my doubt.

Comment: I honestly cannot understand your question. The theorem, whose proof you say you understood *completely*, states precisely what you say you do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the parametrizations $\phi$ and $\psi$ give local coordinate systems $\phi^{-1}$ (on $U'$) and $\psi^{-1}$ (on $V'$) in which that equation holds. $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ are the coordinates of $\phi^{-1}$  and $(y_1,\dots,y_\ell)$ are the coordinates of $\psi^{-1}$. This language appears throughout differential topology/geometry, and so you need to get used to it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I was confused at that part.

Comment: You're welcome. Once you clarified exactly what you were not understanding, it was easy enough to address. :)